# ZedGraph plotting large amount of data

Tags: c#, for-loop, arrays, zedgraph

Hi.

```
            PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
            LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("My Curve", list, Color.Blue,
                                    SymbolType.None);
            for (int x = y; x < buffer.Length; x++)
            {
                list.Add(x, buffer[x]);
            }
```

I have a file its size is 40 mb. I am reading the bytes and writing the data into buffer so `buffer.lenght` gets a large number. Thus program throws out of memory exception because of long for loop. How can i draw all bytes without taking out of memory exception.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pre-process the byte array generating a smaller data set that is 2x the maximum horizontal width or your chart.

To display a chart that is maxWidth pixels wide you will do *something like this*.

```
int window = (buffer.Length / maxWidth) + 1;

for (int x = 0; x < buffer.Length; x += window)
{
    double min = double.MaxValue;
    double max = double.MinValue;

    for (int j = 0; j < window; j++)
    {
        int index = x + j;

        if (index < buffer.Length)
        {
            double value = buffer[x+j];
            if (value < min)
            {
                min = value;
            }

            if (value > max)
            { 
                max = value;
            }
        }
    }

    list.Add(x, min);
    list.Add(x + (window - 1), max);
}
```

If you zoom in you need to recalculate the point list so that you do not end up with the saw tooth line.

Comment: I set some values to maxWidth those are 128,256,1024,4096.Data looks fine for all values but i want to know should i change this value according to file size? Do you have a suggestion about maxWidth value?

Comment: You do not need to change maxWidth according to the file size, but one the width of the graph in pixels. I would suggest 1920, 2560, or 4096 if you want to fix the value.

Comment: Take a look at [FilteredPointList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_FilteredPointList.htm).  You can load your buffer into it, then set the bounds of the data and the number of points to display.  As long as you have memory this will remove some of the complexity of having to refresh your point list.  You only have to update your list now when the window bounds exceeds your data.